# Open a Access Form from a button click

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am trying to open a form, "Form_cadastroProdutos", when a buttom is clicked in another form, say, Form_menuPrincipal.

Here's the code for the button:

```vb
Private Sub btn_cadastrarProduto_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm Form_cadastroProdutos
End Sub
```

It gives me this error when I click the button:

[image: Error of wrong data type]

I tried to put it between quotation marks as below, but it gives me an error.

```vb
Private Sub btn_cadastrarProduto_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Form_cadastroProdutos"
End Sub
```

[image: Error when between quotation marks]

These are my forms:

[image: List of forms]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out finally. I have to write the form without the "Form_" prefix, with quotes:

```vb
Private Sub btn_cadastrarProduto_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm ("cadastroProdutos"), acNormal
End Sub
```

I also have to specify the mode in which I want to open the form, `acNormal` for execution mode.
It now works.